# jquery not working in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I have a dynamic dropdown creating by jquery. In Home Component there has a div with id **currencyvalue**, dropdown will create on it by jquery function that is in common.js and jquery.ddslick.min.js. Jquery loaded before 
Home component load that's why dropdown is not populated.

So i want to load jquery after home component loaded so jquery function will work.

Code : Home Component

```js
Home Component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as $ from  '../../assets/js/jquery.min.js';
import '../../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js';
import '../../assets/js/jquery.ddslick.min.js';
import '../../assets/js/common.js';

// import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }

}

/*      Common.js    */

Common.js

var ddData = [
{
    text: "Bitcoin",
    value: 1,
    selected: true,
    description: "",
    imageSrc: "images/bitcoin-icon.png"
},
{
    text: "Ethereum",
    value: 2,
    selected: false,
    description: "",
    imageSrc: "images/ethereum-icon.png"
},
{
    text: "Dash",
    value: 3,
    selected: false,
    description: "",
    imageSrc: "images/dash-icon.png"
},
{
    text: "Litecoin",
    value: 4,
    selected: false,
    description: "",
    imageSrc: "images/litecoin-icon.png"
}
];

$('#currencyvalue').ddslick({
data: ddData,
width: 190,
imagePosition: "left",
selectText: "Select your Choice",
onSelected: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}
});
```

```html
Home Component Html

<div class="col-sm-6">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <label for="selvalue" class="textwhite text-center font16 pb10">Crypto</label>
                                    <div id="currencyvalue">

                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Where's your jquery function call in home component? You've to make call from ngOnInit/ngAfterViewInit in some cases, so, it will work

Comment: But jquery functions are in common.js file and i have imported

Comment: Post your jquery code also in question which you want to execute in HomeComponent

Comment: @Shantanu, i have added common.js code

Comment: Thanks @Shantanu, I have no idea about ngAfterViewInit  life cycle of angular. from ngAfterViewInit i have found solutions. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your common.js function inside one function lets say like this:

```
function InitializeDropdown(){
 $('#currencyvalue').ddslick({
 data: ddData,
 width: 190,
 imagePosition: "left",
 selectText: "Select your Choice",
 onSelected: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
 }
}
```

Now, into your `HomeComponent` use `ngAfterViewInit` to call this function

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    (window as any).InitializeDropdown()
}
```

Remember I have not tested this code.